# List splice assignment space complexity?

Tags: python-3.x

I believe that splicing lists in python will always create a shallow copy of the list. However, does this still hold true for splicing assignments?

For example:

```
list[::10] = list[10:20]
```

Does list[::10] create a new list? If my understanding is correct, list[::10] does not use any space but list[10:20] uses space by creating a new list

Answer (score 2):

Using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) we can look at what the Python interpreter is actually interpreting our code into.

```
from dis import dis

dis('l[::10] = l[10:20]')
```

gives us

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (20)
              9 BUILD_SLICE              2
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
             25 BUILD_SLICE              3
             28 STORE_SUBSCR
             29 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can see that there are two [`BUILD_SLICE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_SLICE) operations, one for `l[::10]` and the other for `l[10:20]`.  So both slices are represented in memory by objects.

Edit:

It's worth noting that this is the disassembled bytecode for CPython 3.5

CPython is the "standard" implementation, but other Python implementations/versions may differ.