# Trapping rain water: Bug in brute force approach

Tags: python, c++, arrays, algorithm

I have been looking at different algorithms for the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/trapping-rain-water/description/) on Leetcode beginning with [approach 1](https://leetcode.com/articles/trapping-rain-water/?page=1). The problem requires one to calculate the total water area (column width = 1) if the array values were heights of walls.

The first approach finds the minimum height of the maximum wall heights of the left and right sides of each column and adds water to the top of the given column if the column height is less than the minimum. The minimum is taken as this is the highest the water collected can reach. To calculate the maximums of each side requires making `n-1` traversals for both left and right.

I code in Python but here's the code in C++ as per the solution given on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/articles/trapping-rain-water/?page=1).

```
int trap(vector<int>& height)
{
    int ans = 0;
    int size = height.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int max_left = 0, max_right = 0;
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--) { //Search the left part for max bar size
            max_left = max(max_left, height[j]);
        }
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) { //Search the right part for max bar size
            max_right = max(max_right, height[j]);
        }
        ans += min(max_left, max_right) - height[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I noticed that the maximums of the left and right columns include the current column in the outer loop iteration.This way the lowest value you can get is 0. Please confirm that this is correct. I used `min()` between `0` and the `potentialWater` to be collected in my code.

I looked at the code and rewrote it in my own way but I am getting `0` as my total rain water collected where I should be getting `6`. Where is the error in my code?

```
class Solution:
  def trap(self, height):
    """
    :type height: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """

    if len(height) <= 2:
      return 0

    water = 0
    for col in range(1, len(height)-1):
      maxLeft = 0
      maxRight = 0

      for index in range(col):
        maxLeft = max(maxLeft, height[index])
      for index in range(col+1,len(height)):
        maxRight = max(maxRight, height[index])

      minHeight = min(maxLeft, maxRight)
      # print(col, minHeight)
      # minHeight = min(max(height[:col]), max(height[col+1:]))
      potentialWater = minHeight - col
      # print(potentialWater)
      # water += potentialWater
      water += max(0, potentialWater) # in case this is the highest column

    return water

solution = Solution()
height = [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]
print(solution.trap(height))
```

Comment: Related: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: No idea whether this is your problem, because it's too much of a mass code dump, but from a quick glance, the C++ code is including `i` in the inner loops, but your Python code is excluding `col` in the equivalent inner loops. You really should be rewriting this stuff in idiomatic Python (e.g., `maxRight = max(height[col:])`), so off-by-one errors don't even arise in the first place. (This would also be a better answer in C++, by the way…) But if you really want to do things at the same level as the C++ code, make sure you're doing exactly the same. Print the loop variables to compare, etc.

Comment: @abarnert, wouldn't `max(height[col:])` be using extra space?  I started with list slicing but commented it out when I realized that I could be using extra space.

Comment: @abarnert, here's where I got the view that slices use auxiliary memory. Please confirm that it is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128421/list-splice-assignment-space-complexity

Comment: @heretoinfinity Yes, it means copying half the list. But for many real-life problems, this doesn't matter—and for most real-life problems where performance matters, you should be using a numpy array or similar rather than a list (and numpy arrays return in-place views when sliced). If you fall into the small set of problems where numpy is not appropriate but you do need to optimize things, then at least get it working first, then optimize once it works.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for the explanation. I was solving this problem for interview purposes and not real-life problems. I tried the slicing first but still had the issue so I switched to something else. Thanks for mentioning numpy arrays and the fact that they return in-place views when sliced. I will remember that when I get the job. Many thanks.

Comment: Also, before optimizing, measure. Of course if the list is huge, the copy will be painful, and may even break your code. But if we're talking only a few thousand elements, it's probably worth wasting a few KB, given how much speed benefit you'll get from the optimized loops inside the slice and single `max` call vs. the slow generic `for` loop and calling `max` over and over.

Comment: Assuming the job actually is in Python (using CPython): if you can not only point out that slicing copies, but also explain how to use `timeit` and `sys.getsizeof` to compare the tradeoffs, then I'd be impressed. (But being able to guess the answers you'd get from those comparisons, I wouldn't even really ask anyone unless they were claiming to be a low-level Python expert or something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple debugging tactics quickly narrow the problem to this line:

```
  potentialWater = minHeight - col
```

Why do you subtract the column *number* from the minimum height???  These aren't at all the same class of quantity.  Instead, you want to subtract the *height* of the current column:

```
  potentialWater = minHeight - height[col]
```

With that change, we get the desired output:

```
$ python3 trap.py
6
```

---

As a comment already noted, you should use Pythonic programming idioms for this, such as replacing

```
for index in range(col):
  maxLeft = max(maxLeft, height[index])
for index in range(col+1,len(height)):
  maxRight = max(maxRight, height[index])
```

with

```
maxLeft = max(height[:col])
  maxRight = max(height[col+1:])
```

Comment: just like I asked abernett above, wouldn't max(height[col:]) be using extra space? I started with list slicing but commented it out when I realized that I could be using extra space.

Comment: here's where I got the view that slices use auxiliary memory. Please confirm that it is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128421/list-splice-assignment-space-complexity

Comment: You're quite correct; `abarnert` already told you everything that I would have said, and a little deeper.

Comment: thanks. Sometimes people don't respond to comments on their own comments hence the reason of posting here as well.